# Logic simplification in sml

Tags: pattern-matching, expression, sml, first-order-logic

I'm creating logic simplification program in sml. But I have a problem for this input:

```
- Or(Or(Var"x", Var"y"), Var"z");
val it = Or (Or (Var #,Var #),Var "z") : formula
 - Simplify it;
```

And it's in an infinite loop.

Here is my code:

```
fun Simplify (Or(True, _)) = True
| Simplify (Or(_, True)) = True
| Simplify (Or(False, False)) = False
| Simplify (Or(x, False)) = (Simplify x)
| Simplify (Or(False, x)) = (Simplify x)
| Simplify (Or (Var (x), Var (y))) = Or (Var (x), Var (y))
| Simplify (Or (x, y)) = (Simplify (Or (Simplify x, Simplify y)))

| Simplify (And(_, False)) = False
| Simplify (And(False, _)) = False
| Simplify (And(True, True)) = True
| Simplify (And(True, x)) = (Simplify x)
| Simplify (And(x, True)) = (Simplify x)
| Simplify (And(Var (x), Var(y))) = And (Var (x), Var (y))
| Simplify (And (x, y)) = (Simplify (And (Simplify x, Simplify y)))

| Simplify (Not(Not(x))) = (Simplify x)
| Simplify (Not(True)) = False
| Simplify (Not(False)) = True
| Simplify (Not(Var (x))) = (Not (Var x))
| Simplify (Not(x)) = (Simplify (Not (Simplify x)))

| Simplify True = True
| Simplify False = False
| Simplify (Var(x)) = Var(x);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three cases which are really suspicious:

```
| Simplify (Or (x, y)) = (Simplify (Or (Simplify x, Simplify y)))

| Simplify (And (x, y)) = (Simplify (And (Simplify x, Simplify y)))

| Simplify (Not(x)) = (Simplify (Not (Simplify x)))
```

Basically, if x and y couldn't be simplified further, `Simplify x` and `Simplify y` will return `x` and `y`. So you will invoke Simplify with the same input as before (`Or(x, y)`, `And(x, y)` or `Not x`). You can test that your function doesn't terminate with some examples such as: `And(And(Var "x", Var "y"), Var "z")` and `Not(And(Var "x", Var "y")`.

The idea of simplification is that you have `True` or `False` in an inner clause, you want to propagate it to outer levels. Note that you will not try to simplify if x and y are irreducible.

**UPDATE:**

Your function could be fixed as follows:

```
fun Simplify (Or(True, _)) = True
    | ... (* Keep other cases as before *)
    | Simplify (Or (x, y)) = (case Simplify x of
                                True => True
                              | False => Simplify y
                              | x' => (case Simplify y of
                                         True => True
                                       | False => x'
                                       | y' => Or(x', y')))

    | Simplify (And (x, y)) = (case Simplify x of
                                 False => False
                               | True => Simplify y
                               | x' => (case Simplify y of
                                          False => False
                                        | True => x'
                                        | y' => And(x', y')))
    | Simplify (Not x) = case Simplify x of
                             True => False
                           | False => True
                           | x' => Not x'
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I think you tried to use top-down approach which is not really appropriate. I rewrite the function using bottom-up approach to make it shorter and more readable:

```
fun Simplify True = True
 | Simplify False = False
 | Simplify (Var x) = Var x
 | Simplify (Not x) = (case Simplify x of
                         True => False
                       | False => True
                       | x' => Not x')
 | Simplify (And(x, y)) = (case Simplify x of
                             False => False
                           | True => Simplify y
                           | x' => (case Simplify y of
                                      False => False
                                    | True => x'
                                    | y' => And(x', y')))
 | Simplify (Or(x, y)) = (case Simplify x of
                            True => True
                          | False => Simplify y
                          | x' => (case Simplify y of
                                     True => True
                                   | False => x'
                                   | y' => Or(x', y')))
```

Comment: But without them if I have: Not(And(And(False, Var("x")), Var("y"))); then it won't be simplified further to "True".

Comment: Now I've got plenty of "Error: syntax error: deleting  BAR ID DARROW"

Comment: Try to reindent bars (|) so that they are after `case ... of`. I thought you need ideas more than concrete code.